# how can i get category name instead of the ID

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project using Django Rest Framework, I have two models ( contacts and category)

So a contact can be in a category, I have a foreign key between the models, I would like to know how can I get data category name instead of getting the id number.
This is my code :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Contact(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

My serializer

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"
```

Result I get :

```
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"category": 1     ( i want to get the name of the category instead of the id )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got into same situation.I think there is no need to write another function if you can achieve this by one line of code and adding it to fields using **source**.You can also try this:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source="category.cat_name", read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'category']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution

```py
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            "first_name": obj.first_name,
            "last_name": obj.last_name,
            "category": obj.category.cat_name
        }
```

Comment: Is correct to keep Foreign key, or i should do one to one ?

Comment: ForeignKey is fine. I would also add a `related_name` to the ForeignKey field. ```category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='contacts')```

Comment: how ?? can you explain to me more please :) related_name

Comment: what is the role of related_name

Comment: that way now you can do something like 

```
category = Category.objects.first()  
contacts_in_category = category.contacts.all() # or filter here
```

Comment: related_name let's you do a reverse lookup quickly with a name that you decide upon.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_category_name')

    def get_category_name(self, obj):
        if obj.category_id:
            return obj.category.cat_name
        return ""

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"
```